# When can the child start using adult cosmetic products?

Tags: toddler, age-appropriate, hygiene

**Child is 2.6 years old.**

It is winter here and taking the child to bathroom to wash her face with soap is difficult for me as well as her. Water can be warmed but clothes do get wet, hers as well as mine if I and she are not very careful.

So, for past two days, I have been cleaning her face with the [cleansing milk](http://www.khadinatural.com/khadi-cucumber-aloevera-cleansing-milk-cream-with-sheabutter.html).

That is an adult's product. Though this one does not have any harmful chemicals but still since it isn't a baby product so I am not sure whether I should continue using it on her or not.

Also, when can I stop using baby soap on her. I do use skin softening soap for myself. From what age can I use the same for her, as well as adult body and face lotions?

Comment: honestly I think most products labeled for 'kids' are just a sales gimmick. If you are generally aware of problematic ingredients in health & beauty products, then anything that is a pure cosmetic product (and not an OTC product or treatment for things like acne with an active, regulated ingredient) should be fine to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't see any problem using a natural product like cleansing milk on a child. Just remember if she gets it in her eyes it will sting which is why most people use baby products.

Another option is to make your own "Face wipes" to use on her that can be as natural as you want. It will also help with getting the clothes wet.

If you search for "make your own makeup remover cloths" there are lots of DIY recipes. Here is one option that I found quickly: http://www.onegoodthingbyjillee.com/2011/09/if-youve-read-my-blog-lately.html

A quote from the article:

> - For baby wipes: 4 cups warm water (one reader recommends DISTILLED    water to inhibit the growth of mold), 1-2 tablespoons Coconut Oil, and 1-2 squirts of baby wash.

The above mixture is poured over either paper towels (I suggest the half sheets) or those disposable cotton pads. Then store them in an air tight container like an empty wet wipe box or mason jar.

Comment: The coconut oil and the soap will be what inhibits the growth of mold, distilled water probably would help the mold out if anything (As it will have no chlorine/flourine in it) though certainly avoiding those chlorine/flourine could be a good thing.  But +1 from me, we did something similar with our first child for reusable diaper wipes (using washcloths this way).

Comment: Your likely right about the distilled water and mold. I suggest making them in small batches so that you avoid the issue.

Comment: "using a natural product" Would there be a problem using an unnatural product?

Comment: Exposure to unnecessary chemicals would be the main problem using a non natural product.

Comment: It's all chemicals, whether they came from a plant or a chemical reactor.  "Natural" is a marketing adjective without rigor and having poor predictive value for the efficacy and safety of the product so labeled.